# Insert Text into <span> tags before content

Tags: jquery, append, html

I have a question regarding jQuery. I'd like to insert one word before content in a  tag. The reason being, I am using social icons and I'd like for two words to be able to be inserted before the actual span to change the variation. Here is the font I'm using: http://drinchev.github.io/monosocialiconsfont/

If I can do this using CSS, I'd love it - whatever works. I've tried using :before mind you.

Here's what it looks like... for a youtube icon I'd use:

```
<span class="social">youtube</span>
```

The font reads "youtube" and makes it into the youtube symbol. IF i wanted a round icon i'd use:

```
<span class="social">roundedyoutube</span>
```

I am making options for a theme, and I'd like for Social Icons style to be "regular, rounded, round" and upon selection have "rounded" or "circle" to be inserted before the `youtube` in the `<span>` tags. Hopefully I am making sense.

So here's the setup.

1. I have HTML code `<span class="social"> youtube </span>`
2. I have JS code importing the social span into a DIV: `$('span.socialarea').appendTo('#socialcontainer');`
3. I want a word inserted before `youtube` in the html code.
4. I've tried using some of the following:
   `$('span.socialarea').add('rounded');`
   and
   `$('span.socialarea').text('rounded');`
   and
   `$('span.socialarea').before('rounded');`
   The later seemed to work the best but added it outside the span not inside.

Hope that makes sense!
Short version: add a word before the content in a span tag.

Comment: See my update with demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/53r4D/)

```
$(function() {
  $('span.socialarea').prepend('rounded');
});
```

is the one you may be looking for. 
Or with appendTo:

```
$(function() {
  $('span.socialarea').prepend('rounded')
    .appendTo("#socialcontainer");
});
```

It will however create two separate strings in the Chrome browser I use to test so you MAY want this instead

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DTpv4/)

```
$(function() {
  var text = $('span.socialarea').text();
  $('span.socialarea').text('rounded'+text)
    .appendTo("#socialcontainer");
});
```

For more than one you need `each`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/53r4D/)

```
$(function() {
  $('span.socialarea').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();  
    $(this).text('circle'+text).appendTo("#socialcontainer");
  });
});
```

Comment: Sweet, does it. However, one issue is it wont combine the two texts. They appear above each other instead of one word. Any possible way to fix this or?

Comment: Here is what I mean, the font is particular: http://d.pr/i/3N6s if there is a way to make it read it that way that'd be awesome

Comment: the CSS used to read "youtube" and make it into the icon is: `webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -ms-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -o-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
`

Comment: Thanks, one more issue - it's being duplicated now, here's the code I'm using: <span class="socialarea">youtube</span>
<span class="socialarea">aboutme</span> and an image: http://d.pr/i/O0dy

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the jQuery [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) to add your content to the front of the span?  Something like:

```
$('span.socialarea').prepend($("<p>Some new tag</p>"));
```

Or:

```
$("<p>Some new tag</p>").prependTo($('span.socialarea'));
```

Comment: Is this how the code should look? 
$(document).ready(function () {
$('span.socialarea').appendTo('#socialcontainer');
$("rounded").prependTo($('span.socialarea'));
});